# Probability of finding gold coins in a bag

Tags: combinatorics

> In his duffel bag, John has 96 gold coins from different countries.
> However he picks up eleven gold coins, he gets at least three gold
> coins from the same country.

> (a) John concludes that the duffel bag contains at least 20 coins from
> some country. Is John right?
>
> (b) John thinks that it is even the case that in the duffel bag there
> must be at least 21 coins from the same country. Is it correct?

My answers:
a) One can estimate that the percentage of gold coins in the duffel bag is the same as the percentage of the goldcoins that was picked out.  The percentage of goldcoins in the extracted set is $\frac{3 }{11}\approx0.27$. 27 percent of 96$\approx$ 26 coins. $26>20$, so by this estimation, John is right.

b) By the same calculation in a) , we can still assume by simple percentage calculation, that there are 21 coins from the same country, since $26>21$.

But is such simple percentage calculation the right approach here?

Thanks

Comment: "John concludes.." But where is the data ?

Comment: @trueblueanil  missed that out by error. updated OP

Comment: Percentage is not a correct approach. You have added the tag combinatorics, combinatorics is the good approach.

Comment: @Lourrran how would that look like? Is there a formula to consider?

Comment: Have you tried obtaining an upper bound on the number of countries?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Do you mean a ceiling function?

Comment: I am thinking in terms of the Pigeonhole Principle.  If there are too many countries, you will not be able to guarantee that any subset of $11$ coins will contain at least three coins from some country.  What is the largest number of countries that guarantees that you will always obtain at least three coins from one country?  Once you determine that, you can apply the generalized Pigeonhole Principle to answer the two questions.

Comment: How to reach 11 without any group of 3 ? 11= 2+2+2+2+2+1. So, if we have 6 different countries,  there are some arrangements with no group of 3 similar coins. So we should have maximum 5 countries. Or maybe 4 countries with many coins, and 2 country with exactly 1 coin ...  etc etc ; you have to investigate all cases.

Comment: @Lourrran you can actually have up to $9$ countries, as long as you only have one coin from $8$ of them

Comment: @RezhaAdrianTanuharja By the pigeon hole principle, having 96 coins in total, we could have max 96 countries in the bag. However, since John pics 11 coins, where 3 are from one country, then at max 9 different type of coins can occur,  hence we can have at max 9 individual countries in the extracted set.  
Let the maximum number of countries in the extracted set of coins be 9, then if this number is representative for the entire set of 96 coins,  we have $\lfloor\frac{96}{9}\rfloor=10$ coins pr country.

Comment: But you do not answer the question. With 9 country, 10 or 11 coins from each country, it is possible to select 11 coins with 3 similar, and it is also possible to select 11 coins with 1 or 2 from each country.  Your exercize says : 'However he picks up 11 gold coins, he gets at least 3 gold coins from the same country'.

Comment: If you say '$9$ countries' , or $n$ countries, you need to do more job, you need to say in detail how many coins from each country. 9 countries with 88 coins from country 1 and 1 coin from each other country is totally different than 9 countries with 10 or 11 coins from each country. And total  is 96 coins from  9 countries in both cases.

Comment: @Lourrran but we need only to answer if John is right or not. My proposition confirms that he is wrong in both cases, with a minimal proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Part A***

Let's say that we have coins from $x+y$ countries. We have more than one coin from any of the $x$ countries and we have only one coin from any of the $y$ countries.

**Inequality 1**

Even if we take $2$ coins from each of the $x$ countries and $1$ coin from each of the $y$ countries, we will still get less than $11$ coins, so we have an inequality:

$$
11>2x+y
$$

Since $x$ and $y$ must be non-negative integers, the inequality also imply that $5\geq x$

**Inequality 2**

Now suppose that we have a maximum of $19$ coins from any country, we then have the second inequality:

$$
19x+y\geq 96
$$

Combined with the first inequality, we have $17x>85\implies x>5$

**Conclusion**

Obviously $5\geq x$ and $x>5$ cannot be fulfilled simultanesously. Therefore, John was right - we must have at least $20$ coins from one country.

***Part B***

Let's assume that there are maximum $20$ coins from any single country. The second inequality from before becomes:

$$
20x+y\geq 96
$$

Combined with the first inequality from before, we have $18x>85\implies x\geq 5$. Therefore, we found a possible solution - $x=5$ and $y=0$. Indeed, it is possible to have coins from $5$ countries that fulfil the condition without any country having more than 20 coins, the number of coins are:

$$
19,19,19,19,20
$$

Answer (score 0):

a. Suppose it is false: then the number of coins for a country is at most $19$. Follows there is coins of at least $6$ different countries. A possible pick is $<2,2,2,2,2,1>$, contradicting the observations of John.

b. The distribution of coins in the bag could be $<20,19,19,19,19>$. When picking $11$ coins John necessarily pick at least three of the same country as there is only five different type of coins.